# Create an Id Section (StringBuffer Java)

Tags: java

In this code:

```
StringBuffer flux = new StringBuffer(); 
flux.append("[Prestation]\n")
    .append(createElement("Num", getNum))
    .append(createElement("Code",getCode()))

    .append("[IR]\n")
    .append(createElement("Coefficient",getCoefficient()))
    .append(createElement("Quantite",getQuantite())).toString();
```

There are two sections (Prestation, IR). So an element is created only if it was setted previously(creatElement). 
The problem that i would like to print the section title only if that section contain an element. For example, print IR only Coefficient was setted.

How can i do that? can anyone help me ?

Comment: Adding a condition ? You can `append` the `StringBuffer` whener you need, it is not required to do this in one statement (`flux.append().append().append();`). You can simply `flux.append();` then add a condition to add the rest `if(condition) flux.append()`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad idea to 'create' things when making a descriptive string of the state of an object (usually done in `toString`). This may be a naming issue (does `createElement` just format the value as a `String`?). Ignoring that, let's continue.

First note that *method chaining* is just a shorthand for a sequence of calls:

```
flux.append("[Prestation]\n");
flux.append(createElement("Num", getNum()));
flux.append(createElement("Code",getCode()));

flux.append("[IR]\n");
flux.append(createElement("Coefficient",getCoefficient()));
flux.append(createElement("Quantite",getQuantite()));
```

From here you can extract variables (I'll do it for one section for brevity):

```
Object num = getNum();
Object code = getCode();
flux.append("[Prestation]\n");
flux.append(createElement("Num", num));
flux.append(createElement("Code", code));
```

Now you can apply a condition that determines if the section exists:

```
Object num  = getNum();
Object code = getCode();
if (num != null && code != null) {
    flux.append("[Prestation]\n");
    flux.append(createElement("Num", num));
    flux.append(createElement("Code", code));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple split the command and add the condition:

```
StringBuffer flux = new StringBuffer(); 

            flux.append("[Prestation]\n")
            .append(createElement("Num", getNum))
            .append(createElement("Code",getCode()));
 if (getCoefficient() != null) {
            flux.append("[IR]\n")
            .append(createElement("Coefficient",getCoefficient()))
            .append(createElement("Quantite",getQuantite()))
}
flux.toString();
```